# .htaccess trailing slash redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rewrite

What is the best way to redirect:

```
/en/contacts/?SELECTED=Austria

/en/contacts/?SELECTED=Austria/
```

to

```
http://newdomain/contact/
```

I don't know if this is the best way and what $ sign is for:

```
RewriteRule /en/contacts/?SELECTED=Austria/?$  http://newdomain/contact/
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried as suggested

```
RewriteRule /technology/?$ https://newdomain/contact
```

But it does not redirect when i enter in browser `oldomain.com/technology`

When I enter `oldomain.com/technology/` it redirects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regex. It means :

- `/?` : With or without slash
- `$` : At the end of the URI

But I think there is a problem before : /en/contacts/? should be escaped by a backslash : `/en/contacts/\?`

Comment: We used only Redirect 301 without backslash and it is working.
Redirect and RewriteRule have different syntax?

Comment: RewriteRule /technology/?$ https://newdomain/contact
only works with slash, without slash - page not found. There are no symbols that needs to be escaped with slash in this case.
Any ideas?